# Issue with b2body shape of unwell shaped objects (BOX2d + COCOS2d)

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

How to set b2body shape according to inconsistent shape of objects so that it gives perfect collision?

Answer was : user physicsEditor / texturePacker

followed steps and used these tools.

now there is something called GB2ShapeCache.h and .mm , and it gives compile time error as ,

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_GB2ShapeCache", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MYCLASS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

any help to resolve it or any other way to give perfect shape to unshaped sprites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i have found solution, i had just dragged `GB2ShapeCache.h` and `GB2ShapeCache.m` to my xcode. But indeed they were not added to `'Compile Sources'`. which i had to add by my self as Xcode forgot to do the same :)